# Image processing LABVIEW

Tags: image-processing, labview, shape-recognition

How do I use feature detection to **measure dimensions and locate a circle/line/rectangle** in an image on `LABVIEW`. 
For example, lets say I inserted an image into `labview` I want `labview` to detect if it has any shape in it!

Comment: Are you using the vision development module? What have you tried or where have you looked for help so far? Have you read the manuals?

Answer (score 0):

I used lab view in high school for a robotics team and we developed a lot of real time image tracking code that did pretty much that.

What we did was create a little system that took an image checked it for pixels that were a specific Hue, Saturation, and Luminosity, than grouped them together by creating a convex hull around said pixels. We then we scored the convex hull on its linear averages and that was put up against expected results.

And once you get the convex hull you can preform some particle analysis and a few calculations later you have your dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function "IMAQ Find Circles" to locate circles. For lines and rectangles I'd probably write something on my own. Segment the image using IMAQ Threshold and let "IMAQ Particle Analysis" give you characteristics of the resulting blobs.

A sample image of what you're trying to achieve would help to understand the problem you're facing. Please upload one.

Also refer to the image processing manuals for LabVIEW. These two are pretty good and give a lot of examples on how to process images:

NI Vision for LabVIEW User Manual:
http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371007b.pdf

NI Vision Concepts Manual:
http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/372916e.pdf

Answer (score 0):

labview have some method to find shape you can find all of them in vision assistance machine vision part but you need some post processing to use such algorithm after that 
you can use geometry matching and other vi to find any shape you want